# Rust dotenv isn't able to read .env file

Tags: rust, dotenv

I've got a Rust test app that uses dotenv. It's supposed to read a few keys in a .env file located at the project source folder. This is how my main function starts, calling dotenv and reading one of the keys, printing and logging it with a handmade script that handles it:

```
// Depdendencies
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpServer};
use diesel::r2d2::{ConnectionManager, Pool};
use diesel::sqlite::SqliteConnection;
use dotenvy::dotenv;


// Modules import
mod utils;
use utils::*;
mod models;
mod schema;
mod api_modules;
use api_modules::{
    books_handlers, books_relationships_handlers, users_handlers,
};

#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    // Load .env file and set initialization variables
    dotenv().ok();
    log(LogType::Info, "Starting server...".to_string());

    // more code, API initialization, etc
```

The code seems to break at the `log` function, imported from the `utils` module. That module is mostly empty, but it's there to wrap all the utility code that doesn't fall into an API categorization. For now, it looks like this:

```
mod logger;

pub use logger::*;
```

The logger exposes the `log` function, which makes use of three more functions (craft_message, write_to_console, write_to_logfile). They are simple enough not to be added here in order to not clutter the post.

The problem seems to be in write_to_logfile, when I try to read the `LOG_FILE` key from the .env file:

```
fn write_to_logfile(message: &String) {
    let path: String = std::env::var("LOG_FILE").expect("LOG_FILE must be set"); 
    let mut file = OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .append(true)
        .open(&path)
        .unwrap();

    if let Err(e) = writeln!(file, "{}", message) {
        eprintln!("Couldn't write to file: {}", e);
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
     Running `target\debug\rust_web_server.exe`
2023-03-25, Marh:03m - [Info] - Starting server...
thread 'main' panicked at 'LOG_FILE must be set: NotPresent', src\utils\logger.rs:41:50
```

What is the problem here? I thought that calling dotenv().ok() in the start of the main file was enough to read keys from a file and set them as environment variables. This is how my file looks:

```
DATABASE_URL=db
LOG_FILE=logs.txt
```

It's located at the same folder as the main.rs file, so... what's the problem here?

Comment: Instead of calling `dotenv().ok();` can you try `println!("{}", dotenv().unwrap().display());` and tell us what is printed? This should print the path of the `.env` file `dotenvy` loaded, if the call was successful. If the call fails we get an error message that may help finding the root cause of your issue

Comment: It throws the following: thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Io(Error { kind: InvalidData, message: "stream did not contain valid UTF-8" })', src\main.rs:23:29

Answer (score 2):

> It's located at the same folder as the main.rs file, so... what's the problem here?

That's exactly the problem, according to the [usage](https://crates.io/crates/dotenv) `dotenv()`

> will load environment variables from a file named .env in the current directory or any of its parents;

that is the working directory of the program at runtime, with `cargo run` that's the folder where the `Cargo.toml` is.

Additionally the format is without trailing semicolons:

```bash
DATABASE_URL=db
LOG_FILE=logs.txt
```

You should also make sure `.env` is a plain text file, not containing any non-UTF-8 characters, since `dotenv` [loads into `String`s using `BufReader`](https://docs.rs/dotenv/0.15.0/src/dotenv/iter.rs.html#17) everything in it has to be valid UTF-8.

Comment: Okay, I was wrong: actually, the file was in both places, with the same content. So this doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: Are you sure it's there? Called exactly `.env` not `.env.txt` or something by accident, with that I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: I know, the error doesn't seem easy to reproduce. But yes, it's an .env file with no further format, located in the same place as the Cargo.toml file.

Comment: Just tried removing the semicolons, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: The problem according to your latest comment on the question is that your file contains non-utf-8 characters.

Comment: Yes, but... how aren't these UTF-8 characters?: DATABASE_URL=db
LOG_FILE=server_logs.txt

Comment: Since I don't have the physical file to inspect I can't tell you, make sure the editor you use saves as utf-8 not utf-16 (or some other encoding) and it's plain text, not some marked up text. How do you edit your `.env` file?

Comment: You're right; somehow, VSCode was saving that file as UTF-16. Now that I manually changed it, it's finally working.